# How to active car data feature on android P aosp emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-auto

I got [Emulator in document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO137.png)
. It has been included car sensor data. When I git aosp source android P. I ran emulator but no car data future in extended controls.   [android P aosp emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF2uX.png)

How can I enable car sensor data in my emulator?

I added my build number: aosp_car_x86-userdebug

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I tried with my device configuration where I didn't get the "Car data" and "Sensor Replay" options in the Emulator's Extended Controls. This was solved by changing the PRODUCT_NAME configuration in my device's makefile to include "car" in the PRODUCT_NAME string.

You can check the emulator source code here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu.git/+/refs/heads/emu-master-dev/android/android-emu/android/avd/util.c#211